# (Raspberry Pi 3) How to set camera properties using set() function (from raspicam/raspicam_cv.h)?

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

When I try to set parameters for my camera, I get this error during compilation:

> error: 'CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT' was not declared in this scope
>   Camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC3 );

It's like compiler doesn't know about all camera's properties (macros).
I got the same error for `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` and `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT`.

I thought that maybe the error is due to some missing libraries or I wrong installed the [raspicam package](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam/).

The code is here (`FRAME_WIDTH` and `FRAME_HEIGHT` are constants defined by me):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <raspicam/raspicam_cv.h>

raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
cv::Mat image;   

//set camera params
Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC3 );
Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_WIDTH);
Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_HEIGHT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use `cv::` and remove these `CV_` (they are usually legacy flags). You can see their definition [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/include/opencv2/videoio.hpp#L131-L180). Also, `FRAME_WIDTH` and `FRAME_HEIGHT` are not from OpenCV and I don't see where you defined them.

```cpp
// [...]
Camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FORMAT, cv::CV_8UC3);
Camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_WIDTH);   // FRAME_WIDTH?
Camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_HEIGHT); // FRAME_HEIGHT?
// [...]
```

You can also check which properties you can set reading the [`raspicam/raspicam_cv.h`](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam/blob/master/src/raspicam_cv.h#L91-L108):

```cpp
/**Sets a property in the VideoCapture. 
 * 
 * 
 * Implemented properties:
 * cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,
 * cv::CAP_PROP_FORMAT: CV_8UC1 or CV_8UC3
 * cv::CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS: [0,100]
 * cv::CAP_PROP_CONTRAST: [0,100]
 * cv::CAP_PROP_SATURATION: [0,100]
 * cv::CAP_PROP_GAIN: (iso): [0,100]
 * cv::CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE: -1 auto. [1,100] shutter speed from 0 to 33ms
 * cv::CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_RED_V : [1,100] -1 auto whitebalance
 * cv::CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_BLUE_U : [1,100] -1 auto whitebalance
 * cv::CAP_PROP_MODE : [1,7] 0 auto mode
 *
 */

bool set ( int propId, double value );
```

Comment: FRAME_WIDTH and FRAME_HEIGHT are constants defined by me

Comment: @SamuelSandu :)